How to install Notepad on Windows 11 24H2 sandbox?
Windows Sandbox (24H2 version) has no Notepad included. How can I install it?

According to this page - Windows Sandbox from Microsoft, you need to:

Usage

Copy an executable file (and any other files needed to run the application) from the host and paste them into the Windows Sandbox window.
Run the executable file or installer inside the sandbox.
When you're finished experimenting, close the sandbox. A dialog box will state that all sandbox content will be discarded and permanently deleted. Select Ok.
Confirm that your host machine doesn't exhibit any of the modifications that you made in Windows Sandbox.


Follow steps 1 and 2.
You can find notepad.exe in the following folders:

C:\Windows
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_11.2405.13.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Notepad


Due to Notepad now being a UWP on all supported versions of Windows it will be difficult to just copy the executable into Sandbox.
